# rollup - automatically Inject global sass variables to each SCSS file

Tags: webpack, sass, rollup

Is there an equivalent for *Webpack's* [sass-resource-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-resources-loader) but for Rollup?

I want to be able to use *sass variables* defined globally in every `.scss` file without having to import them all at the top of each file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, this one worked for me.

https://github.com/hytromo/rollup-plugin-postcss-retain-sass-data#readme

Comment: please add the code within the answer, the external link as reference is good, but may be not avaliable in the future

Comment: This fork is have been left unmaintained for years... it is highly unrecommended to use such fork and the author should mark it as `deprecated`